# Bot receiving messages with empty content

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My `discord.js` version is `14.0.3`.

I'm trying to make a feature that requires the message content, so I created a `client.on('messageCreate')` event:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  console.log(message.content)
});
```

But the console is sending empty (`''`) strings. Every message I receive has empty content.

I added intents and partials, but it didn't change anything.

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages],
    partials: [Partials.Message, Partials.Channel, Partials.Reaction],
});
```

How do I access the content of messages sent to servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From October 25, 2021, accessing message content now requires enabling a new privilege intent.**

[image: Bot tab on the Discord Developer Portal showing the new message content intent]

This setting needs to be enabled for bots to receive message content.

[More info](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055)